# What is the correct way to offset for a placeholder element when using ng-animate?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have the following plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pl5KaBkFouadAGKSB0Mt?p=preview

Every 3 seconds, a message with my name appears. When the message is not there, in it's place is a placeholder element, these two are accounted for in the following lines:

```
<div ng-switch="main.myValue">
  <div ng-switch-when="true" class="animate">Mike</div>
  <div ng-switch-default class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

My issue with this is that when `Mike` is animating out, for a brief moment both that div and the placeholder div become visible, so effectively the content underneath is pushed down (`div class="more-stuff"`). I'm having a hard time working around this, it seems that the correct way to do this involves using `.ng-stagger` on the placeholder but that seems like overkill and I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to make placeholder element animateable too, and set `position: absolute` on ng-leave phase:

```
<div ng-switch="main.myValue">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" class="animate">Mike</div>
    <div ng-switch-default class="animate placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

and remove stagger CSS rules.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0uhnSNI69N2QMoB7k7sx?p=preview